# Espresso UI-Tests cannot find the views in my xmls and getting noMatchingViewException

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

Heyy, I am writing tests with Espresso for my android app and I am having 2 cases, where Espresso won't find the views.
Here, are the xmls( so you can see the hierarchy and the test classes ):

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <myapp.ui.SafeAreaConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/login_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_color_3_oranges_linear_270"
        tools:context=".fragments.onBoarding.EmailSignInFragment">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo_banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/welcome_figure"
                android:layout_width="172dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_logo_app_transparent"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="40dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/welcome_figure" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/powered_by"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:text="@string/powered_by"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/logo"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/app_name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_name" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="31dp"
                android:layout_height="31dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logo_30x30"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/app_name"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/powered_by"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_name"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
        <myapp.ui.translatable.TranslatableTextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_main_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ceragr_medium"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/email_tip"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo_banner" />
    
        <myapp.ui.translatable.TranslatableTextView
            android:id="@+id/email_input_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/sign_in_main_text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/sign_in_main_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sign_in_main_text" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_input_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue_main"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:hint="example@gmail.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/light_grey_secondary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/sign_in_main_text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/sign_in_main_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_input_label"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </myapp.ui.SafeAreaConstraintLayout>
    ```
    and then the test:
    ```
    @LargeTest
    @HiltAndroidTest
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    class FragmentWithArgsTest {
    
        @get:Rule
        var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    
        private lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController
        @Before
        fun setUp() {
            // Populate @Inject fields in test class
            hiltRule.inject()
            // Create a TestNavHostController
            navController = TestNavHostController(
                ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
            )
        }
    
     @Test
        fun latestValidateEmail() {  //did not pass
            Thread.sleep(7000)
    
            val args = Bundle().apply {
                putString("signInLink", null)
            }
    
            // Create a graphical welcomeFragmentScenario for the EmailSignInFragment
            launchFragmentInHiltContainerFirst<EmailSignInFragment>(args) {
    
                // Set the graph on the TestNavHostController
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.onboarding_nav_graph)
    
                // Make the NavController available via the findNavController() APIs
                Navigation.setViewNavController(this.requireView(), navController)
            }
    
            val editText = Espresso.onView(
                Matchers.allOf(
                    withId(R.id.email_input_text),
                    withHint("example@gmail.com"),
                    withInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS),
                    withParent(
                        Matchers.allOf(
                        withId(R.id.login_layout),
                            withParent(withId(R.id.nav_host_fragment))
                        )
                    ),
                    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.login_layout)),
                    isDisplayed()
                )
            )
    
            editText                  
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(
                    ViewActions.typeText("elefth99@gmail.com"),
                    ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard()
                )
                .check(matches(withInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)))
        }
    }
````

and then the other xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_orange_main">
    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/background_for_welcome"
            layout="@layout/background_for_welcome"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:alignItems="center"
            app:flexDirection="column"
            app:justifyContent="space_between"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/logo_banner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/welcome_figure"
                    android:layout_width="172dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_logo_app_transparent"
                    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/app_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/welcome_figure" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/powered_by"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                    android:text="@string/powered_by"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/logo"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/app_name"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_name" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/eagme_logo_20x20"
                    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/app_name"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/powered_by"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_name"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:alignItems="center"
                app:flexDirection="column"
                app:justifyContent="flex_start"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo_banner">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/connect_with_text"
                    android:layout_width="136dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                    android:text="@string/connect_with"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signin_google_button"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
                <myapp.ui.SigninThumbnailButton
                    android:id="@+id/signin_google_button"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:signin_button_background="@drawable/signin_google_background"
                    app:signin_button_icon="@drawable/google_icon"
                    app:signin_button_text="@string/google"
                    app:signin_button_text_color="@color/not_so_black" />
    
                <myapp.ui.SigninThumbnailButton
                    android:id="@+id/signin_facebook_button"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:signin_button_background="@drawable/signin_facebook_background"
                    app:signin_button_icon="@drawable/facebook_icon"
                    app:signin_button_text="@string/facebook"
                    app:signin_button_text_color="@color/white" />
    
                <myapp.ui.SigninThumbnailButton
                    android:id="@+id/signin_email_button"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:signin_button_background="@drawable/signin_email_background"
                    app:signin_button_icon="@drawable/envelope_icon"
                    app:signin_button_text="@string/email"
                    app:signin_button_text_color="@color/white" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_signin_skip"
                    style="@style/ButtonSignInText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                    android:text="@string/skip"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/signin_email_button" />
    
            </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_text"
                style="@style/TextFooter"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
                android:text="@string/legal_agreement"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and then the test class:

```
    @LargeTest
    @HiltAndroidTest
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    class SignInFragmentTest {
    
        @get:Rule
        var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    
        private lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController
    
        private lateinit var emailSignInButton: ViewInteraction
        private lateinit var googleSignInButton: ViewInteraction
        private lateinit var facebookSignInButton: ViewInteraction
    
        private lateinit var skipButton: ViewInteraction
    
        @Before
        fun setUp() {
            // Populate @Inject fields in test class
            hiltRule.inject()
            // Create a TestNavHostController
            navController = TestNavHostController(
                ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
            )
    
            val args = Bundle().apply {
                Pair<String, Any>("mode", AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationModes.SIGNIN)
            }
    
            // Create a graphical welcomeFragmentScenario for the WelcomeFragment
            launchFragmentInHiltContainerFirst<SignInFragment>(args) {
                // Set the graph on the TestNavHostController
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.onboarding_nav_graph)
    
                // Make the NavController available via the findNavController() APIs
                Navigation.setViewNavController(this.requireView(), navController)
            }
            //        Intents.init()
        }
    
    //    @After
    //    fun tearDown() {
    //        Intents.release()
    //    }
        @Test
        fun testSignInSkip() { //passed
            Thread.sleep(7000)
            skipButton = Espresso.onView(
                Matchers.allOf(
                    ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.connect_button),
                    ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.connect),
                    isDisplayed()
                )
            )
    
            skipButton.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    
            // Verify that performing a click changes the view to home page
            skipButton
                .perform(click())
    
            //check if HomeActivity/ HomeFragment
        }
    
        @Test
        fun testGoogleSignIn() { //did not pass
            Thread.sleep(7000)
            googleSignInButton =
                Espresso.onView(
                Matchers.allOf(
                    ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.signin_google_button),
                    ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.google),
                    isDisplayed()
                )
            )
            googleSignInButton.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            googleSignInButton.perform(click())
        }
    
        @Test
        fun testFacebookSignIn() { //did not pass
            Thread.sleep(7000)
            facebookSignInButton = Espresso.onView(
                Matchers.allOf(
                    ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.signin_facebook_button),
                    ViewMatchers.withParent(
                        ViewMatchers.withParent(
                            IsInstanceOf.instanceOf(
                                ViewGroup::class.java
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    isDisplayed()
                )
            )
            facebookSignInButton.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            facebookSignInButton.perform(click())
        }
    
    
        @Test
        fun testEmailSignIn() { //did not pass
            Thread.sleep(7000)
            emailSignInButton = onView(
                Matchers.allOf(
                    ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.signin_email_button),
                    childAtPosition(
                        childAtPosition(
                            ViewMatchers.withClassName(Matchers.`is`("com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout")),
                            1
                        ),
                        3
                    ),
                    isDisplayed()
                )
            )
    //            Espresso.onView(
    //            Matchers.allOf(
    //                ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.signin_email_button),
    //                ViewMatchers.withParent(ViewMatchers.withParent(IsInstanceOf.instanceOf(ViewGroup::class.java))),
    //                isDisplayed()
    //            )
    //        )
    // emailSignInButton.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    
            // Verify that performing a click changes the NavController’s state
            emailSignInButton
                .perform(click())
    
            //from SignInFragment To EmailSignInFragment
            MatcherAssert.assertThat(
                navController.currentDestination?.id,
                Matchers.equalTo(R.id.emailSignInFragment)
            )
        }
    }
```

ALso an example of the stacktrace for the test : LatestValidateEmail , I am getting is :

```
    androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (view.getId() is <2131296487/com.crowdpolicy.onext.igme:id/email_input_text> and an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getHint() matching: is "example@gmail.com" and an instance of android.widget.EditText and editText.getInputType() is <32> and view.getParent() view.getId() is <2131296572> and is descendant of a view matching view.getId() is <2131296572> and (view has effective visibility <VISIBLE> and view.getGlobalVisibleRect() to return non-empty rectangle))
    
    View Hierarchy:
    +>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1280, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=1 fl=#85810100 fmt=-2 wanim=0x103045b needsMenuKey=2 clr=0x1}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
    |
    +->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@bc31964, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
    |
    +-->ViewStub{id=16909220, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@b2677cd, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
    |
    +-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@46e8b93, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
    |
    +--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131296312, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@e73cace, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
    |
    +---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131296327, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@86c4def, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
    |
    +---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@285c5da, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
    |
    +----->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@db360e8, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
    |
    +------>FragmentContainerView{id=2131296636, res-name=nav_host_fragment, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@d8a65a6, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
    |
    +------->FragmentContainerView{id=2131296636, res-name=nav_host_fragment, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@1d1a394, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
    |
    +-------->ConstraintLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@965d12c, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=7}
    |
    +--------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131296358, res-name=background_for_welcome, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1188, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@44b598a, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
    |
```

I used Espresso recorder test to get the views, but even with this, my tests are not successful ! Any idea how to fix it ? Any help is appreciated, because I have spent a lot of time on this with no result !

Comment: Is there a reason your view matcher contains several different conditions? Would it not be matched by simplifying it to an `onView(withId(R.id.email_input_text))`?

Comment: @agoff I tried that too, but I got the same error, any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Are you positive the view is on the screen and visible? Looking at the hierarchy output, I'm not seeing the view in there.